# Is there an automated way in SQL Server to add delta records to a table weekly from a .CSV file and a FTP secure site?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with training records of students with a 9 digit primary key for each student. Every week I will receive a delta file (new courses the students finish) in a `.csv` file dropped on a secure FTP server.

Is there an automated way to update the table weekly with the new records? The table is in SQL Server 2014. Thank you in advance.

```
SELECT 
    STUDENT_KEY, (New record might be added)
    FIRST_NAME, (New record might be added)
    LAST_NAME, (New record might be added)
    COURSE_NAME, (New record might be added)
    COURSE_NUMBER, (New record might be added)
    SCORE, (New record might be added)
    SCORE_DATE, (New record might be added)
    TRAINING_HOURS (New record might be added)
FROM   
    STUDENTS_REC
```

Comment: Load the data into a stage table, then push it up into the actual table using a `MERGE` statement. Stick that in a job and schedule it.

Comment: Of course there is a way.  You need to build up the process.  A routine to fetch the file from the FTP server will need to be created.  Next, a process that loads the data into a table in the database, preferably a staging table, and finally a procedure that moves the data from staging table to the target table.  If you are using SQL Server, you should be able to automate the entire process using SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

Despite it's relationship to healthcare, I use Mirth Connect (Now called [NextGen Connect Integration Engine](https://www.nextgen.com/products-and-services/nextgen-connect-integration-engine-downloads)) for this sort of thing regardless of industry.  [Open source](https://github.com/nextgenhealthcare/connect), fairly lightweight, and infinitely configurable it can pickup CSV and other text, XML, and EDI Documents from a variety of sources, transform them, then push them to SQL Server.  Using an Interface Engine like Mirth Connect results in monitorability and a dashboard, with built in error logging, archiving, and other benefits.

[image: Mirth Summary]

The same is also easily accomplished if you want to go the other direction.  For example, you could have a query which sends results back to a SFTP server.

For the use case you describe (CSV to SQL), the solution might look like:

1. Create a new channel in Mirth
2. On the "Summary" tab, set Data Type to "Delimited Text" on the source connector, and XML on all the other connectors. (XML is the "native" Mirth format - you will not actually work with the XML directly)
3. In the "Delimited Text" inbound properties, set the column delimiter to "," and set the "Column Names" to "STUDENT_KEY,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,COURSE_NAME,COURSE_NUMBER,SCORE,SCORE_DATE,TRAINING_HOURS" or whatever the columns present in the CSV File are.

[image: Summary Page]

4. On the "Source" tab, set the connector type to "File Reader" and add set the FTP server information.  Key parameters would be "Method" of "FTP" or "SFTP" depending, Server and Path, filename filter, username, and Password.
5. Decide how to handle "Completed" files - you can either delete them or move them with the "After Processing Action".  Leaving it at "None" will result in reprocessing all messages indefinately.
6. I recommend enabling "Check file age" to avoid reading the files while they are still being written.  60 seconds is usually sufficient for all but the largest or slowest writers.
7. Set the encoding of the files to be read, usually utf8 (which is I believe the default)

[image: Source tab]

8. On the destination tab, select Connector Type of "Javascript Writer"
9. Write your script, calling SQL Server as needed:

Example Javascript with E4X:

```javascript
var dbConn;
var result;

try {
    dbConn = DatabaseConnectionFactory.createDatabaseConnection('net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver','jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433/DBName','username','password');

    // insert header
    var params = new java.util.ArrayList();
    params.add($('originalFilename'));
    result = dbConn.executeUpdateAndGetGeneratedKeys('INSERT INTO ImportFiles ([Filename], ImportDate) VALUES (?, GETDATE());', params);
    result.next();
    var headerId = result.getInt(1);

    // save in the channel map (message data) for fun
    channelMap.put('headerId', headerId);

    // loop over rows and insert
    var msg = new XML(connectorMessage.getEncodedData());
    for each (row in msg.row) {
        if (row.Location.toString() == "Current Location") {
            // skip headers
            continue;
        }

        params = new java.util.ArrayList();
        params.add(headerId);
        params.add(row.SpillmanPatientID.toString());
        params.add(row.AdmitDate.toString());
        params.add(row.Location.toString());
        params.add(row.TransferDate.toString());
        params.add(row.LastName.toString());
        params.add(row.FirstName.toString());
        params.add(row.MiddleName.toString());
        params.add(row.SuffixName.toString());
        params.add(row.Birthdate.toString());
        params.add(row.Sex.toString());
        params.add(row.SSN.toString());
        dbConn.executeUpdate('INSERT INTO dbo.ImportData (ImportFileID, SpillmanPatientID, AdmitDate, Location, TransferDate, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, SuffixName, Birthdate, Sex, SSN)' 
            + ' SELECT ?, ?, ?, GETDATE(), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?', params);
    }

    // call sproc
    params = new java.util.ArrayList();
    params.add(headerId);
    dbConn.executeUpdate('EXEC dbo.ProcessImportFile ?', params);
} finally {
    if (dbConn) { 
        dbConn.close();
    }
}
```

Note that the members of "row" are whatever you specified for column names in the source connector setup.

10. Click "Deploy Channel" on the left
11. Verify operation using the dashboard.  You can double click a channel to see the messages that have been sent (with results and error logs), and can right click and hit "Resend Message" to try again (for example, if you make a change to the script).

After you get things set the way you want, I would recommend:

1. On the summary tab in the Channel Setup
2. Set "Message storage" to "Production" or "Raw" - you can always move back to Development and reprocess a message if you have a problem
3. Set "Metadata Pruning" to (for example) 7 days
4. Set "Custom Metadata" - Remove SOURCE and TYPE, add originalFilename and any data you added to the channel map in your javascript.  In the example above, I create a "headerId" which could be used to correlate between SQL and Mirth.